# How to migrate Cppunit tests into GoogleTest?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, cppunit, googletest

I have a bunch of module tests written in CPPunit with some mocks created by hand. I am looking for a way to migrate them to GoogleTest as smoothly as possible. 
Have you tried such an operation?
 What was the effort needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Google Test` and `Cppunit` seem to share somewhat the same syntax for invoking tests but as I suspect have too much differences in that syntax.

I'm almost sure you can't somehow automate it and this operation would require rethinking and recompositioning of your tests to follow the `Google Test` semantics (if you use something specialized to create your mocks, then porting them to `Google Mock` would require even more effort, simply because `Google Mock`'s approach is not the obvious one and is actually complicated).

I would say that you'd better rethink the following questions: "why do I need to port my tests", "what would be the benefit of this operation" and "do I really want to study a whole new testing framework and then rewrite all of my tests for some purpose".

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you can use google test from another framework (cppunit, in your case): 
https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Letting_Another_Testing_Framework_Drive

Answer (score 0):

To some extent I agree with @Kotti. Automatic conversion will be non-trivial for the tests, so you'd need to consider whether the number of existing tests justify the effort.

I'm a huge fan of the Googlemock framework, and if you make a significant investment in manual mocking, then porting your mocks to Googlemock could have a huge benefit to your ongoing testing costs.

If this is the reason for considering the port, then remember that Googlemock can work with other test frameworks - not just Googletest. (NOTE: I have not used this feature, but have seen online reports its use)

Comment: I've done this -- it's really quite simple to use Googlemock with CppUnit